# Matlab, using straight line equation to remove rough edges

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using the following image which I have segemented :

[image: Before]

I need to smooth the line where the image is segmeneted so that it looks like this:

[image: After]

I have read that the best way to to do this is to use the straight line equation:

```
y=mx+c
```

and find four points along the segmented area. However I am unsure of how I go about finding four points.

Can anyone please guide me?

Thanks

I have code which I have used to decide which side of the image needs to be segmented:

```
  s= regionprops(BW2, 'BoundingBox');
  BW3 = imcrop(BW2,s.BoundingBox);%crop the image 


  total1=sum(BW3(:,[1:5]));%get the total of the first 5 columns in the image
  totalFirst=sum(total1);
  total2=sum(BW3(:,[end-4:end])); %get the total of the last 5 columns in the image
  totalLast=sum(total2);
  %breast profile classified such that if the sum of the first 5 rows is
  %greater than the last 5 rows then the breast is right orientated else it
  %is left orientated. 
  if totalFirst>totalLast 
    O=1; % o for right
  else 
    O=0; % 1 for left 
  end
```

Comment: Is this a mammogram (x-ray of the breast)?

Comment: How do you want to find the four points? Is it done manually, by clicking four times on the edge to be smoothed? If it must be automatic, then how could the code determine which side of the image is to be smoothed? Or is it always in the upper left corner?

Comment: Yes, I have segmented the pectoral muscle from it and need to smooth the line

Comment: It must be done automatically. I already have code which determines what side. I will add this code to my question.

Comment: Does it need to be a straight line? What about the quality of the edges for the rest of the image? A mode filter would tidy up the whole image a fair bit, but it wouldn't give the perfectly straight line you are describing. Also, you could use principal component analysis to automatically re-orient the image.

Comment: I just need to concentrate on the segmeneted section. Yes it must be a straight line.. i need to make the first image look like the second image

Comment: Would the line be always cut by the boundaries of the image or can we have a whole curvature and becoming a straight line? Sorry, not too familiar with mammograms.

Comment: Yeah its always cut by the boundaries of the image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the image is **right-oriented**, as in the example above - **left-oriented** images can be flipped using `fliplr`. Assume that pixels of value `0` are **black**, and pixels of value `1` are **white**. The simplest algorithm I can imagine is the following:

**1.** Starting from the upper left corner, find the column index of the pixel in the first row, which is white. Let's denote it by `j0`.

```
j0 = 1;
while BW3(1, j0) ~= 1 
  j0 = j0 + 1;
end
```

**2.** Starting again from the upper left corner, find the row index of the pixel in the first column, which is white. Denote it by `i0`.

```
i0 = 1;
while BW3(i0, 1) ~= 1 
  i0 = i0 + 1;
end
```

**3.** The coordinates of these two white pixels are `(1, j0)` and `(i0, 1)`, respectively. The points on the upper left side of the line connecting these two points (equation: `j = a * i + b`) have to be colored black:

```
a = (1 - j0) / (i0 - 1);
b = j0 - a;
for i = 1:i0
   for j = 1:round(a * i + b)
      BW3(i, j) = 0;
   end
end
```

**4.** Some pixels on the lower right side of this line remain black. We have to color these white. The easiest way is to set the color of a *strip* of pixels on the lower right side of the line to white. Let's denote the width of this strip by `w`.

```
w = 20; % This depends on the resolution and the noise level of the image
for i = 1:round(i0 - w / a)
   for j = max(1, round(a * i + b + 1)):round(a * i + b + w)
      BW3(i, j) = 1; 
   end
end
```

**Notes**

In step **1.**, instead of checking the value of a single pixel on the first row, it's better to compare the mean value of its neighborhood (of size `n`) to a threshold (`t`):

```
n = 10; t = 0.9; % These depend on the resolution and the noise level of the image
c = 0:(n - 1);
j0 = 1;
while mean(mean(BW3(1 + c, j0 + c))) < t 
  j0 = j0 + 1;
end
```

Similarly, in step **2.**:

```
i0 = 1;
while mean(mean(BW3(i0 + c, 1 + c))) < t 
  i0 = i0 + 1;
end
```

**Result**

[image]

I uploaded the code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppisdt5wy3rsccx/BreastImageCorrection.zip).

Comment: Thank you! How do I actually find the column index of the pixel in the first row which is white and the row index of the pixel in the first column which is wbhite?

Comment: thanks.. I am getting the follwing error : '
Attempted to access c0(250); index out of bounds because
numel(c0)=249.' Error in  (line 1BreastSegmentation Line87)
while c0(i0) < 0.5

Comment: I assumed that every pixel is either white or black, that is, has a value of either 1 or 0. If this is true, then averaging `n` columns should give a column full of values between 0 and 1. Plotting `c0` could help to find out what happens... Anyway, isn't the image accidentally left-sided? The above code works only on right-sided images (those with the same orientation as of the above example image). If you have a left-sided image, flip it first: `if totalFirst < totalLast, BW3 = fliplr(BW3); end`.

Comment: Yes this is true, every pixel is black or white. Sorry I forgot this only worked on right sided images but u applied the flip and I am still getting the same error. I do not understand why this is, as each pixel has value of 0 or 1

Comment: Would you pls upload the img somewhere?

Comment: I updated my answer. I also uploaded the code to dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppisdt5wy3rsccx/BreastImageCorrection.zip

Comment: Thanks so much. I will give this a go now and let you know how I get on!

Comment: OK, I'll look at it tomorrow. It's 1:15 AM here, so I must go to sleep :)